# RenderBody with jQuery Ajax calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm think that I'm doing something wrong here in *.Net Core.*

I have layout with `@RenderBody`

Problem is - I'm doing `jQuery Ajax` calls, my *Actions* returning me *Partial Views*. That works good.

Problem is, I don't see any path of *Controller* and *Action* in *URL*, can't refresh page, I am returned to the *Home*.

Another problem with *Partials Views* I can't solve is - **Scripts**:
I can include all scripts in *Layout*, but some *partials views* requiring 2-3 scripts, another *partials views* different 2-3 scripts. I can't split usage, I don't want to throw all in one layout.

Can't add them in the *Partial View* because `jQuery` loads on the end.

If I include them on the end of the *Layout* page - then *Click* events and other stuff work when I navigate to different partials view.

I think my approach here is somewhere really bad, all my navigation is done by `jQuery Ajax` and returning *Partial Views* from the *Controllers*.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems you're attempting to create a SPA (single page application) without actually understanding what goes into that.

Right now, you're managing you application server-side, i.e. your routes are server-side, your views are server-side, etc. As a result, you need to go back and forth between the server to get your "pages", which negates the entire point of having a client-side application. What you need to do is shuffle all of that *client-side*, using a framework like Angular, React, Vue, etc.

These frameworks will provide things for your like templates, two-way data-binding, client-side routing (including using things like the History API to create virtual URLs allowing you to browse back and forth, reload, etc. without losing your client-side state). At that point, your backend ASP.NET Core app becomes more like an API, simply handling data transfer to/from your client-side app and something like your database, etc.

You might also be interested in Blazor, particularly server-side Blazor. It's *very* early in development, so it's probably not a good idea to start building mission-critical apps on it, yet., but it does provide a much more fluid server-side to client-side experience. Essentially, it creates reactive HTML documents that use SignalR under the hood to communicate back to the server transparently to get/update state and keep the server-side and client-side portions in sync. It's pretty slick, but like I said, still very much a "preview" at this point.